# Display woo-commerce product gallery not showing the zoom button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am creating one eCommerce website using woocommerce. I am just using the woocommerce plugin and add the products. In that product shows the zoom button on the right side when clicking the zoom button it redirects to the woocommerce Gallary it shows the full-size button and close button but not displaying the zoom button.

How I must do to show the effect of slider and zoom?

In theme, it shows the three buttons. I Use this theme:https://accesspressthemes.com/theme-demos/?theme=accesspress-store

[This screenshot our theme in that theme this zoom button is displayed but in my website not shows use this same CSS but not displaying.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyfPT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the feature is there in the theme but not showing then it could be that it is turned off by default. Themes can sometimes give the store owners an option to toggle such features.
You can check under the `Appearance->Customize` section or any other theme settings page that your theme comes with.

You should probably be raising this issue with the theme support otherwise.